# How do I slide in one div after the previous div slides out and hides then repeat with newer divs without making a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs, each with an image nested inside of them. When the first div slide in from the left, I want it to slide out after 10 seconds then "fadeOutLeft" then `hide()`. 
After the first div slides out, I would like the second div to take its place and do the same thing.

I have tried finding something related to this, and I've tried using `setTimeOut()` to make this work, and they just don't all transition out like the first one.

Is there an easier approach than to use the one I have tried below? Also reference, I'm using animate.css: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Here is the code that I tried making and scratching my head at for a while:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- Refresh the Page every 900 seconds (15 minutes) -->
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
  
  <!-- Animation CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
  <!-- Latest version of jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
   body {
    background: #000000; /*transparent;*/
   }
   
   #website {
    animation-delay: 0s;
   }
   
   #twitter {
    animation-delay: 10s;
   }
   
   #youtube {
    animation-delay: 20s;
   }
   
   #discord {
    animation-delay: 30s;
   }
  </style>
  
  <!-- Animating the div tags -->
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#website").addClass("fadeInLeft");
    setTimeout(w, 10000);
    $("#twitter").addClass("fadeInLeft");
    setTimeout(t, 20000);
    $("#youtube").addClass("fadeInLeft");
    setTimeout(y, 30000);
    $("#discord").addClass("fadeInLeft");
    setTimeout(d, 40000);
   });
   
   function w(){
    $("#website").addClass("fadeOutLeft").fadeOut();
   }
   function t(){
    $("#twitter").addClass("fadeOutLeft").fadeOut();
   }
   function y(){
    $("#youtube").addClass("fadeOutLeft").fadeOut();
   }
   function d(){
    $("#discord").addClass("fadeOutLeft").fadeOut();
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div id="boxes">
   <div id="website" class="animated">
    <img src="website.png" >
   </div>
   
   <div id="twitter" class="animated">
    <img src="twitter.png" >
   </div>
   
   <div id="youtube" class="animated">
    <img src="youtube.png" >
   </div>
   
   <div id="discord" class="animated">
    <img src="discord.png" >
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"...without making a slideshow?"* What you are describing is a slideshow. Did you want help with a slideshow but call it a giraffe instead?

Comment: I didn't know how to word it at the time lol. I guess it technically is a slideshow. Although when people think of slideshow they think of adding wrappers and what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `animation-delay` and `setTimeout` for the other images, the `fadeOutLeft` animation and the animation for the jQuery method `fadeOut()` have to wait 10s+20s, 20s+30s or 30s+40s to begin, but the `display:none;` property of the `fadeOut()` method fires instantly when the function is triggered (after the `setTimeout`, 20s, 30s or 40s).

I would suggest to remove the `animation-delay` property, then group `fadeOutLeft` of the first image with the `fadeInLeft` of the second image in the same code block (and so on) and control the delays with `setTimeout`:
https://jsfiddle.net/c12oxy6m/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! It works much better now and doesn't flicker weirdly! I had a feeling it was a timing issue but didn't know how to attack it.